Ubuntu 24.04 installation bug
I tried to install Ubuntu 24.04, but I got this problem.
Sep 20 23:12:20 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall: 
Sep 20 23:12:21 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Sep 20 23:12:59 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET: 
Sep 20 23:16:30 ubuntu subiquity_event.3536[3536]: subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET:


Bugs are off topic here.
